# I want to compare two columns in excel having 500000 records

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, comparison

I have two columns in excel file having almost 500000 records in each col. I want to check how many records from col 1 are present in col 2. I'm using below formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$D$1:$D$495154,0)),"",A1)
```

But I'm unable to apply this formula to entire column in one shot. I have to drag this formula for more than half hour which is very much time consuming. Also, fill option is not working.

Can someone tell me how to apply this formula in one shot or any other to compare these two col easily.

Comment: You could do it with VBa  then you'd only click a button

Comment: I think this is mostly slow because you have 500000 formulas. Even without autofilling or dragging down, your machine has to recalc 500000 matches nested in an if. Even with VBA, this won't be a fast operation. I am wondering if you could use an array formula to figure this out in one fell swoop? Likely wouldn't be "fast" still, but that is relative.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding a formula to a blank column and you want it filled down as far as the data in another column you can use the following technique:

1. Move the cursor to the top of the blank column. Put in your header cell if needed, and the formula below that, or at the top of the column.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>, this will take the cursor to the bottom of the empty column
3. <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move into the column with the data.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>, this will move to the last item in the column with data. It is faster to do it this way in case there are any empty sections in the data rather than trying to jump down to the bottom of the column with data directly
5. <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to move back into the column with the data
6. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> will select the range to fill
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will fill the formula down

This should be much faster than grabbing the bottom right hand corner of the cell with the formula and dragging down.

Answer (score 0):

This is a faster way than dragging down:

1. Apply this formula to the first row and the last row
2. Copy this formula from the first row
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to select all rows between 1st and last rows in this column
4. Paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Edit:

To move quickly to the first or last row, first go to a column that already have all rows filled with data, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with no scrolling or dragging required.

1. Select the cell with your formula.
2. Click in the Name Box (to the left of the formula bar, highlighted in the image below) and type the address of the last cell you want to fill down to. In my example, I want to fill the formula from `A1` to `A500000`, so I type `A500000`.

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will extend the selection to the cell you specified.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill the formula throughout the selected range.